# Install Gnome 3.10 in Ubuntu 13.10 without breaking Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10

I just installed the Ubuntu 13.10 RC. Everything works fine so far.
The thing is i want to also install Gnome 3.10 and i worry that this will break Unity.

I know how to install the latest gnome release:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions
```

My question is if i should do anything else to ensure that i can have both environments without something breaking?

**Edit**
I followed the orders [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html) so after the above steps i also did:

- Switched to GDM

  sudo apt-get install gdm

And select GDM instead of LightDM when prompted.

- Removed the Ubuntu overlay scrollbars:

  sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar

Comment: Do you have any updates on this issue?

Comment: @pacofvf Yes, sorry i forgot. I just switched to GDM as this article shows: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html. I didn't encounter any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently trying out both, and installing Gnome 3.10 through the ppas you have listed does not break Unity. However Gnome 3.10 does not work perfectly for me, there are quite a few small but nagging issues (which are sort of expected). For example,

1) Brightness and gnome shell extension settings does not persist across reboots.

2) Nautilus (Files) seems buggy, it often freezes.

3) Gnome lock screen freezed a few times for me.

But Gnome 3.10 looks impressive overall, so you can give it a try (looks like you are interested).

I have installed Cinnamon 2.0 as well, and that in fact broke Unity. I can no longer login to Unity now, but Shell and Cinnamon work. There is actually an article on Softpedia that also points out the conflict between Unity and Cinnamon 2.0. I am not sure how to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have encountered 1 and 3 as well, but not 2. Concerning the lock screen freeze, I found that hitting escape twice helps: first to go back to lock screen with the clock, the second time to reopen the login screen. Despite minor issues, the UX is considerably better than Unity, and arguably better than the interfaces on MacOS and Windows.

Comment: In my case the mouse pointer has disappeared from Unity, however you can move the mouse and (blindly) click with it, but the pointer is invisible. The same happens at the login screen. In Gnome shell there's no such problem

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to gnome 3.10 in ubuntu 13.10, it preety works but font size was really a mess right after upgrade.

I solved enabling and then disabling "large fonts" in the accessibility options. Hope this helps someone else.