# missing mouse after gnome install

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I recently installed gnome3 on my Ubuntu partition (on a suspicion that unity is memory leaking) and now my mouse has disappeared from both the login screen and after logged in. I used [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358989/install-gnome-3-10-in-ubuntu-13-10-without-breaking-unity) to install it on my Ubuntu 13.10 this morning so it should be the most recent version I think. Does anyone know what causes this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- open a terminal an run `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`    OR
- run `dconf-editor` and navigate to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor` and set the schema `active` to false.

Discussions can be find [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694758)

Comment: I have no `org.gnome.settings-daemon` in my Xubuntu desktop 14.04 did there change something?

Answer (score 0):

- Open `System Settings` > `Displays` by pressing window key and search for system settings in dash.
- In the `Displays` window, you will see an Unknown monitor. Click it and disable it

Comment: When I search "System Settings" or just "setting" in the Unity Search Panel I get no results.

Comment: run this command on terminal `gnome-control-center`

Comment: I selected the displays option in the gnome-control-center and it opened saying "Could not get screen information" across the middle of the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an old NVIDIA card try installing

```
apt-get install nvidia-common
```

**Important:**
Don't run `nvidia-config` and **don't** create any `xorg.conf` file now!

Then reboot

```
apt-get install nvidia-173
```

reboot

I don't know if there has to be several reboots, but the first time I tried it without installing `nvidia-common` first and this messed up with my resolution for my LCD monitor