# can i install Unity on gnome 3?

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 3.10, can I install Unity on Gnome, or will it break Gnome?

Or should I do a fresh install?

Thanks

Comment: Even though the answer below is correct, Unity does not work properly. Wallpaper is not drawn, when desktop icons are enabled. There is also a lot of lagging when minimizing an open window. The only way is with a fresh install. Gnome and Unity still do not play nice together.

Comment: Additional, this broke my system. I have had to do a fresh install. So I would not advise adding Unity to Ubuntu Gnome, whatever those guys have done to Ubuntu, it is hacked to bits...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue with Gnome 3.10 breaking Unity a few months back, but that has been fixed.   More in that issue [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358989/install-gnome-3-10-in-ubuntu-13-10-without-breaking-unity?rq=1). However, I know of no issues with Unity breaking Gnome.

If you wish to install Unity you can either use the command line(terminal) or the Software Center(can't remember what it is called in Gnome, Munon?)

In a terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

in the Software Center search for `ubuntu-desktop` -search exactly as typed, including the hypen to find it easier.

Either way will download and install Unity and all the programs that go with it....In my system it shows as 9.5MB to download and 32MB once installed but I think that is only the Unity desktop, with all other programs, I would expect it to be near 100MB download, about 300MB after install.

---

After you install Unity select "Ubuntu" as the DE on login by clicking on the icon in the upper right of the box you type your password in.  The menu will open allowing you to select Gnome or Unity.

You can switch between them without rebooting **but** you will have to log out of one and into the other so **you will** lose any **unsaved** info when you log out.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have found Gnome to be too limiting.. So will change when 14.04 is released.. Appreciated..

Comment: I didn't want to ask a duplicate question, but this doesn't appear to work in my current setup. A brand new fresh install of ubuntu 17.04 gnome desktop, I ran `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and did a reboot. I wasn't prompted which DM to use and there's no "DE" as mentioned in the second half of this answer. If there's nothing added here in the next short while, I'll start my own question. cheers

Comment: @Madivad  that's strange, the only thing I can think is that you still need to enable "partner" sources in the software and updates program, it's in the "Other Software" tab.  You will then need to do a reload to get the updated lists.  However, if you did not have this enabled I would think that you would get a "not found" message.  I would check to see if it's enabled if so try and install again, if that fails, it may either be a bug or require a different command.  If you need to ask a new question, link to this answer and say why it didn't work to help prevent it being marked a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ain't gonna break Gnome. Just select "Unity 2d" from login screen, or if you want to use both at same time (Unity and Gnome-shell) , there's a option for activate Unity in Compiz settings.