# Upgrade from Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, 14.04

I'm currently running Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 but I'd like to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity instead of Gnome Shell. How can I go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: possible duplicate of [can i install Unity on gnome 3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429556/can-i-install-unity-on-gnome-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try by opening a terminal and type:

```
unity --replace
```

Log off and you should see UNITY as a choice to log into. Choose UNITY and log in. (Click on the icon to the right of your name and you should then see a list of Desktop Environments to log into)

See if that works for you.