# Disadvantages Installing Gnome on Ubuntu unity

Tags: gnome, software-installation

I want to install Gnome on Ubuntu unity i want to know is there a risk of getting my Ubuntu not work after boot are there other disadvantages of installing gnome on Ubuntu unity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Gnome 3.10 in Ubuntu 13.10 without breaking Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/358989/install-gnome-3-10-in-ubuntu-13-10-without-breaking-unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will boot but you will have to change the desktop environment from the log in screen.

The downside is you will have 2 application sets

I recommend this method

1 Download Ubuntu Gnome Remix [HERE](http://ubuntugnome.org/)

2 install to USB/CD

3 Boot USB/CD

4 Choose instll ubuntu

5 IMPORTANT Choose the option Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to Gnome remix (or something simmeler, upgrade is the important word)

6 install

This will change your Unity version for the Gnome version while saving your home folder

Documentation is [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation)

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for.